# Flutter: App upload file to local server but not to remote server

Tags: flutter, upload

I am trying uploading a image using below code.

```
  String _urlsegment =
      Explika.producaoFlag ? 'https://www.remoteserver.pt' : 'http://10.0.2.2';

  var stream = http.ByteStream(
      DelegatingStream.typed(compressedFileImage.openRead()));
  var length = await compressedFileImage.length();
  var uri = Uri.parse('$_urlsegment/explika/api/upload');

  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

  var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('fotoaluno', stream, length,
      filename: '${Explika.getAluno().id}.jpg');

  request.files.add(multipartFile);
```

Everything work fine using localhost. When i try send image to remote server nothing happens.
The end point is ok: i tested it using postman and all worked well.

**Summing up**:

uploading using **APP to LOCAL server** - OK

uploading to **LOCAL server using POSTMAN** - OK

uploading using **APP to REMOTE server** - Fail (No error occurs but file does not reach server)

uploading to **REMOTE server using POSTMAN** - OK

Any ideas on what is going on? Do I need to enter any special permissions in the app manifest?

Comment: Are you checking both the app on debug mode?

Comment: Yes. I tested too in release mode... same results.

Comment: You need permission only when you are running app in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter sends the images with mime type 'application / octet-stream'. The server was waiting for files with mime type 'image / jpeg', so it automatically rejected the file.